# C# and Paradox database

Tags: c#, paradox

I have to develop software in C # that needs to read (read only) data from other software. The other software (I will call K.) uses Paradox for its databases. So I have a folder with .DB files (eg ARTICLE.DB), but also .PX, .YG0 / YG1 / YG2 and .XG0 / XG1 / ​​XG2 that the "K" software generates and uses.

I created an ODBC link using the driver "Driver do Microsoft Paradox".
In the parameter settings, I informed the "K" software directory (where the .DB files are, etc ...).

The software works fine but when I run the "K" program, my software can not access the data. I have this error:

```
ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft] [ODBC Paradox] External table is not in the expected format.
```

If I close the software "K", my program works again properly.

Additional information : the software "K" data engine uses "Borland BDE," I saw a lot of settings here but nothing that speaks of "connection sharing" or otherwise. I also know that the software "K" creates a PDOXUSERS.NET and some .LCK files, I think files are locked by this, but I have no idea what I can do to "force" read on them.

Have you ever encountered this problem or worked with Paradox database?
I'm interested in any research track.

Thank you.

Comment: It is very hard to answer your question, as it is not even a real question. Without apiece of code, or something similar, nobody will be ab le to help you with your problem.

Comment: I found some posts about Paradox, I think some people may know it and help me a little bit. And maybe, i will found a solution to my problem with various opinions.

Comment: I think your main problem is that the ODBC driver you are using is inadequate. Either it is designed to work with an older version of the Paradox tables, or it is designed only to extract data from tables that are no longer in use by their applications. Don't give up -- other developers are successfully doing what you intend.